# I think I fried my laptop but I'm not sure

Tags: laptop, usb, laptop-repair

Help I think  fried a laptop from the usb port and I started thinking dont laptops have surge protectors if so it's it repair able because I need money and I want to sell it

Comment: What makes you think it's 'fried'?

Comment: Well it doesn't have a disk drives so u got a usb one and then it wansnt working so I plugged a cord that wasn't for it, it was for a subwoofer my usb disk drive was melted and my laptop shut off and hasn't turned back on since

Comment: yup, sounds like you fried it. Once you let out the magic smoke, you can't put it back in again.

Comment: So there's no surge protector no nothing dang how much do you think I could sell this fried laptop for because I still need money

Comment: But the power source that was to strong fed from the wall in to the disk drive not the computer it's self

Comment: Your first mistake was using a cord from another device. Obviously, it was not the proper power rating and it destroyed the circuits. The value is basically worthless now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most USB ports don't have serious surge protectors. If you manage somehow to feed power into the USB port you will in 999 out of a 1000 cases have fried the motherboard of the computer beyond any hope of repair.

There is something you can try though: There is small change most of the laptop still works.
(This will not make it fit for sale as fully working.)

- Remove the battery.
- Remove all external cables/plugs including the power-cable/adaptor.
- Leave it be for 10 minutes. (To let charge and/or heat dissipate.)
- Connect the power-cable, leave the battery out.
- Try to switch it on.
- If it goes on most of it is still in working order. Switch it back off and remove the power.
- Add the battery. Turn it back on. See it that works. If so, the battery is OK.

Now you can reconnect various stuff. Some or all of your USB ports may be fried. Test them one by one with a USB mouse or keyboard. Don't even attempt to test the one you blew up. You may cause additional short-circuits making things worse.

Comment: @jokrkillah - Would be nice to know the reason this answer was even selected as the solution.

Comment: @Ramhound I was wondering too... Never got an accept that fast :-)

Comment: Thank sorry I've been busy but the charging light flashes on it still won't turn on so I think it is fried